# Best Way to Restore Object State on Startup?

Tags: java, mysql, persistence

I have a Java application that receives orders from a remote server then logs into an account and executes the order (I.e, purchases product and ships to correct address).

I am storing the account details (such as username, password, funds remaining in account) in an object called "AccountDetails". I am also storing the purchase details (such as shipping address, first and last name, product ID and so on) in an object called "OrderDetails).

Throughout the execution of program both account and orders will be added to program on constant basis.

My question is - if I exit application and then launch the application I understand the program needs someway to instantiate all previous objects (such as all pending orders and account details).

What is the best way to do this?

I understand I would store  "the state" of each  object in a MYSQL database and then when I launch program connect to DB and instantiate object. However, I'm not sure exactly the best way to instantiate the object.. And do I have the general right approach here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could serialise the object every time it is changed or if your application has a GUI [serialise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) the object and save it in some file(MYSQL database in your case) when the user clicks save button.

Your constructor should look something like this

```
public foo(){
        if (file has your object)
            //code for deserializing
        else
            //create new object
    }
```